# Can we create an instance of class type at the specified location in memory?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++'s “placement new”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/cs-placement-new)

Can we create an instance of class type at the specified location in memory?if yes then how and where we should use such programming techniques?

Comment: @Greg: I don't think so. That question is asking what it is. This question is asking how to do something (where the answer is, with placement `new`). I'd find this one when searching, not that one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can. Use [`new(area)` operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax).

[Another discussion at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/cs-placement-new).